# Running php on Hortonworks sandbox

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtual-machine, remote-server

I am trying to design my front end for my back end services which involves hadoop and hive. I was successfully able to open up XAMPP server on port 8085 of Hortonworks 2.4. For that I had to stop httpd services already running. I was also successfull in writing php codes which talked with mySQL services. However some thing astonishing which I have noticed right away is that on firing hadoop or hive or ambari commands, this is what I am getting - 
-bash: hadoop: command not found
-bash: hive: command not found
-bash: ambari: command not found
I think there is some problem with PATH Variables. Can u help me identify root cause and is it possible to run XAMPP services from inside of HDP 2.4 (which uses CentOS 6.9) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of going with the approach of running two different apache servers on the same machine, which was messing up everything, you decided to use the Hue server itself for hosting my webpages.

Additional configurations on HDP-2.4 includes :

1) Adding Proxy for `/var/www/html` on hue.conf file

2) Installing PHP

3) Upgrading MySQL to 5.5.

I hope this will be sufficient to get your scripts up and running on any sandbox.